# accessing a text field in a tableView SWIFT

Tags: swift, tableview, segue, custom-cell, nsindexpath

I have a tableView.  When the cell is tapped/selected, the cell expands down to reveal several assets.  One asset is a text field.  Another is a "submit" button.

I need to access the user input from the text field when the Submit button is pressed.  How can I do this?

Important: I can't use didSelectRowAtIndexpath as the cell is already selected/expanded.

Currently I have on the customCell the following:

```
@IBAction func submitButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    // prepareForSegue is on mainVC
    self.textString = self.textField.text
    println(self.textString) 
 }
```

On the "prepareForSegue" in MainVC I have the following:

```
       var cell : CustomCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell") as! CustomCell

        let path = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            println(cell.textField.text)
            self.newText = cell.textString
            self.newInt = self.newText.toInt()

            println(self.newText)
            println(self.newInt)
```

the following code properly `prints(self.textString)`
However,
`cell.textString`, `self.newText` and `self.newInt` are always `nil`.

Any idea why?

Comment: give it a unique tag, then search your view for the element with that tag

Comment: what do you mean, a tag?  Isn't cell.textString it's tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample code.

```
@IBAction func submitButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

        // prepareForSegue is on mainVC
            let indexPath = self.tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
            let selectedCell = self.tableView!.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath!) as! UICustomCell!//your custom cell class.

            self.textString = selectedCell.textFied.text //textFied is your textfield name.
            println(self.textString) 
 }
```

For swift 2, this code is working  based on row index

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 0) // This defines what indexPath is which is used later to define a cell
                let selectedCell = sptableViewObj.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! AddBillerTableViewCell!

                self.textFieldTwo = selectedCell.spTextfield.text //textFied is your textfield name.
                print(self.textFieldTwo)
```

Comment: Awesome, I added this to the segue (not the button in the CustomCell Viewcontroller, and It appears to work!  Time to get dinner, then fully implement what I'm working on.  Thank you Amit89!

Comment: This works fine for those in which all UITableViewCell are visible. Just check same when you are having around 10-15 cell and you are first cell is not visible. Now try to access first cell. Application will crash. Anyone having solution for the same ?